# Filter a DataGrid on a Text box

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I search an example or sample to filter the WPF DataGrid column elements by a textbox.

[image]

Something similar to [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpf_datagrid_filter.aspx) (the given example uses a *WPFToolkit*... apparently abandoned by Microsoft...)

XAML

```
<Canvas>
    <DataGrid Height="200" Name="dataGrid1" Width="200" Canvas.Top="23" />
    <TextBox  Name="textBox1" Width="120" />
</Canvas>
```

cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private List<Personne> persons;
    ICollectionView cvPersonnes;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        persons = new List<Personne>();

        persons.Add(new Personne() { Id = 1, Nom = "Jean-Michel", Prenom = "BADANHAR" });
        persons.Add(new Personne() { Id = 1, Nom = "Gerard", Prenom = "DEPARDIEU" });
        persons.Add(new Personne() { Id = 1, Nom = "Garfild", Prenom = "THECAT" });
        persons.Add(new Personne() { Id = 1, Nom = "Jean-Paul", Prenom = "BELMONDO" });

        cvPersonnes = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(persons);

        if (cvPersonnes != null)
        {
            dataGrid1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = cvPersonnes;
            cvPersonnes.Filter = TextFilter;
        }
    }

    public bool TextFilter(object o)
    {
        Personne p = (o as Personne);
        if (p == null) 
            return false;

        if (p.Nom.Contains(textBox1.Text))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

}

public class Personne
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nom { get; set; }
    public string Prenom { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can filter the Items in the DataGrid by binding it to an `ICollectionView` that supports filtering.

Details [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20101003082605/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126.aspx) for .NET 4. The process is the same for .NET 4.5, but it seems the documentation has been lost. There's a small mention to it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx) under the "Grouping, Sorting, and Filtering" heading.

edit: at the time this was originally written, the WPF toolkit had not been abandoned by Microsoft.  The controls that used to be part of it are now in the framework, and the toolkit was alive and doing well [here](http://wpf.codeplex.com/)

Comment: could you comment my code edit? How does the filtering OnTextboxTextChange work?

Comment: @vlad Looks like you spoke too soon about it not being abandoned.

Comment: Abandoned is probably the wrong term -- the toolkit was integrated into .NET 4.0+.  'Relocated' might be a better word...

Comment: First link is broken.

Answer (score 7):

I have seen at various sites much ado about this matter...

To filter the latter being a datagrid using a datatable as the source, which is quite common to make the code below:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Table1");

//fill your datatable...

//after fill...
dataGrid1.DataContext = dt;
IBindingListView blv = dt.DefaultView;
blv.Filter = "NAME = 'MOISES'";
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several solutions, but in my opinion, the best solutions are the ones which uses only `DataGrid` styles without inventing a new inherited `DataGird` type. The followings are the best I found:

- Option 1: which I personally use: [Automatic WPF Toolkit DataGrid Filtering](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/DataGridFilterLibrary.aspx)
- Option 2:  [Auto-filter for Microsoft WPF DataGrid](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpffiltering.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have written my own FilterDataGrid Control, it's much more flexible than the ones provided on CodeProject or elsewhere. I can neither post the full code here, nor can I publish it.

But: Since your datasource is most likely wrapped into a ICollectionView, you can do something like this:

```
    public void ApplyFilters()
    {
        ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ItemsSource);
        if (view != null)
        {
            view.Filter = FilterPredicate; 
        }
    }

    private bool FilterPredicate(object item)
    {
        var yourBoundItemOrRow = item as BoundItemType;

        return aFilterObject.Matches(yourBoundItemOrRow);
    }
```

You can implement any filter logic easily based on this concept. Even very, very powerful filters. Note: I have those methods in my own class derived from datagrid. They can be adapted to work outside of the grid, too, for example in a UserControl

Comment: could you see my code update. How do you filter when the user are typing in the textbox?